# How to create a project to support both scala-2.10 and scala-2.11 in maven

Tags: scala, maven

I want to support both scala-2.10 and scala-2.11 for my project. So I create 2 sub module for both scala-2.10 and scala-2.11. Now my problem is that they both depends on one common module (common-module) which require scala as well. Then How do I organize my whole project structure.  Here's my current project structure. One approach I know is to use separate profile for scala-2.10 and scala-2.11. But I want to build module-scala-2.10 and module-scala-2.11 via one single maven build command instead of building the project twice.

```
project-root
   * common-module
   * module-scala-2.10
   * module-scala-2.11
```

What kind of scala version should I use to compile common-module ? If this is the wrong project structure, how should I organize that ? Thanks